# Changing the title of the page to dynamic title when window onblur

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the title of the page when visitor at another tab. I checked the forum but I need something like this;

```
    (function titleScroller(text) {
    document.title = text;
    console.log(text);
    setTimeout(function () {
        titleScroller(text.substr(1) + text.substr(0, 1));
    }, 200);
}("Come back please ❤" + " " +"Miss you ❤" + " " + "Hello? ❤" + " " ));
```

**or can I add scrolling title to this code?**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // any code js
    var title = document.title;
  var alttitle = "Miss You ❤";
  window.onblur = function () { document.title = alttitle; };
  window.onfocus = function () { document.title = title; };
    
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for `visibilitychange` event in your code and trigger whatever function you like.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", event => {
  if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    console.log("tab is active")
  } else {
    console.log("tab is inactive")
  }
})
```